# custom label in 'messageWhenValueMissing' attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customlabel

I have used custom label in `messageWhenValueMissing` attribute but it doesn't get displayed in UI.

Is there a way to use custom label in `messageWhenValueMissing`. This is necessary since multiple countries will be using the component and they need it in their own language.

```
<lightning:select label="Reason" value="{!v.reasonValue}" required="true" 
 messageWhenValueMissing="{!$label.c.please_provide_reason}">
```

Comment: did you try by setCustomValidity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the keyword `Label` is case sensitive in this context. With a quick test I was able to reflect the message from a custom label using `Label` (starting with UPPERCASE L).

Change the keyword from `label` to `Label` and that should work, as below:

```
<lightning:select label="Reason" value="{!v.reasonValue}" required="true" 
                  messageWhenValueMissing="{!$Label.c.please_provide_reason}">
```

Comment: Yes this works, looks like `Label` is case sensitive only in such scenarios cuz this works correctly `<h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">{!$label.c.Select_reason_for_reopenin}</h2>`

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit odd. I would have expected this to have the same behavior everywhere but doesn't seem to be the case.